# What's the meaning of Nora's expression?

Tags: marriage-story

In Marriage Story (2019), Theater director Charlie won MacArthur grant, which gave him a lot of money. He and his ex wife actress Nicole fought for child custody. A family lawyer, Nora, who fights for her, won the custody case:

> Nicole: And we're not taking any money, right?
>
> Nora: We withdrew our claim for the MacArthur, which I think we could have gotten, by the way, and they're not asking for any of the show.

Nora's line doesn't make sense to me here. I mean she doesn't say who "they" are and also isn't explicitly clear as to what is meant by "any of the play".

Comment: I've not seen the movie yet - so I'm not posting this to be an answer, but since this is a divorce movie and this is her lawyer speaking why wouldn't "they" be the other side, i.e. Charlie and his legal team?

Comment: ...and "any of the show" sounds like asking for a percentage of the profits.

Answer (score 2):

In the court when the lawyets of both the sides were arguing, Jay on belahf of Charlie said that Nicole was getting a fair amount of money which should be split between charlie and nicole.

> Your honor, I don’t see why we should be paying any support money at
>   this point. In fact, Charlie should be entitled to half of her TV
>   salary, present and future earnings on the show.

To which Nora said

> Charlie has just received the enormous sum of six hundred and fifty
>   thousand dollars in the form of a MacArthur grant for the theater work
>   he has conducted during the marriage.

[Marriage Story](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiK_PLkpuLoAhUT7XMBHZ2wAGIQFjABegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com%2F2019%2F12%2Fmarriage-story-ampas-script.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1pKXCULRiHhK7xIIZRHDOt)

Nora: We withdrew our claim for the MacArthur, which I think we could have gotten, by the way, and they're not asking for any of the show.
Hence, hefre 'they' means Charlie and Jay,and 'any of the show.' means the TV show in which Nicole was selected.